# Are the variables declared without self independent in Python class methods? or Is it static?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

I know that class variables are static and instance variables are independent of each other. However, I am not sure whether a variable declared without self in a class method is independent or static. For example, if you look at the source below

```
import threading
class Calculator(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name  

    def sum(self, a, b):
        result :int = 0
        result = a+b
```

The result in the sum method above was created without self. If i create two instances of a thread object and start at the same time, assuming that the sum method of the two instances is accidentally executed at the same time, I want to know whether the value of the result variable is independent between instances or static.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a *local* name. It is created separately for each execution of `sum`. There is no way that one execution of `sum` would access the `result` of another execution of this method.

> I want to know whether the value of the result variable is independent between instances or static.

It is not static, it is even independent when running the method multiple times on the *same* instance. It is not related to the instance nor the class. Its scope is the function only.

This scoping is not specific to methods, but is true for any function with local names.

Comment: I found out for sure. Thank you for sharing your valuable knowledge~